# jQuery - Display an element on hover of another

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover

This could be done easily in CSS if the element that needs to be displayed was a child of the hover, but it isn't; it's in a different section of the document.

I'm trying to have the menu display upon hovering over the '[ + ]' element.

Live: http://blnr.org/testing

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bUqKq/5/

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("header[role='masthead'] #container #left nav#static span").hover(
        function(){$("header[role='masthead'] nav#active").show();},
    );
});
```

Comment: He wants to know how to display the menu when hovering over the [+]

Comment: How to have a specific element display upon hovering over an element in a different section of the document

Comment: The jQuery code I've posted does not do anything.

Comment: There is s syntax error in your code and you haven't chosen/loaded the jQuery library. Also as IDs are unique, you don't have to write such long/inefficient selectors http://jsfiddle.net/fRQN9/

Comment: Thank you! Is there a duration function in jQuery that would allow the menu to display for a specific amount of seconds after hovering as to allow a user to get to the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drastically simplify this by just only showing the id's you are interested in. No need for the rest of the selectors that you are using as ID's are required to be unique.  Note I also provided both hover-in and hover-out functions as I am assuming you want to hide the element after hover condition ends.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#static span").hover(
            function(){
                $("#active").show();
            },
            function(){
                $("#active").hide();
            }
        );
    });
```

Alternately you could just us single closure with toggle() like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#static span").hover(
            function(){
                $("#active").toggle();
            }
        );
    });
```

Comment: much nicer than binding to mouseover and mouseout.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example where you hover over one element and a completely different element is changed,

http://jsfiddle.net/bUqKq/6/

```
<div id="one">hover here</div>
<div id="two">hover here2</div>
```

```
$("#one").on("mouseover",function(){
    $("#two").css({
        color:"red"
    })
});

$("#one").on("mouseout",function(){
    $("#two").css({
        color:"black"
    })
});

$("#two").on("mouseover",function(){
    $("#one").css({
        color:"red"
    })
});


$("#two").on("mouseout",function(){
    $("#one").css({
        color:"black"
    })
});
```